# php form process - unknown input names for quantity increase / decrease

Tags: php

I have an online store, and the page `mycart.php` will display user`s purchases like this :

> image - title - price per unit - quantity - total price

The product IDs and Quantities are held in `$_SESSION` arrays. (Is this good ?)

So if the user want 2 pieces of one product and 3 pieces of another product:

1. How to generate the `<input>` tag (`<input id="product1" name="product-1647">`?)
2. How to iterate through that input if the attribute `name="product-1647"` is dynamic generated?

I've studied a website and they generate inputs like above.

```
<input type="text" id="product1" name="product-23342">
<inpyt type="text" id="product2" name="product-47385">
...
```

But i can't figure it out how the post-processing is done.
Any advice will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html

```
<input type="text" id="product1" name="product[23342]">
<inpyt type="text" id="product2" name="product[47385]">
```

php

```
foreach ($_POST['product'] as $prod_id => $prod_value){
  if ($prod_value){
    // do whatever
  }
}
```

Comment: This is brilliant ... ok i will use your example .. but just for the info ... how did that website managed the `<input name="product-324234">` .. i'm just curious ?

Comment: If you are make use on the id attribute for JavaScript.

Comment: They have `<form method='POST'>` and `<input type=submit name=submit>` to recalculate. They don't use java for post processing

Comment: I think they are using iteration on `$_POST[]` itself .. `foreach($_POST[] as $key => $value) {}` and then `exploding` $key am i right ?